# How to use the SQL from PyCharm DB Console in Python code?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question, but I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days.

I have connected PyCharm to a MariaDB. I can run SQL against the DB and get information back as expected. This include creating tables, inserting rows, removing rows, etc...

How the heck do I implement said SQL from the DB console in code using IDE? Right now I can't figure out how to get the code and the SQL to work together. I've Googled this over and over using different phrases yet always get back to tutorials on how to hook PyCharm up to a database but not how to access the database from the IDE using Python.

Alright - I need to put it in code. Let's say I have this:

```
foo = bar
```

How do I get it here:

```
INSERT {foo} INTO mytable
```

Another way to think of it:

> I have England(Python). I have France(SQL). I just need to build a
> Chunnel (Get Python to communicate with the DB).

Tech Specs:

I'm using Pycharm Professional 2020.2.1
connecting to a remote machine MariaDB
Ubuntu 20.downloaded-yesterday

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to install a "driver" such as [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) (other packages are available) and use it to provide connection and cursor objects that allow querying the db in Python.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that now.

Comment: So - is it safe to think as the DB tools in PyCharm only share a UI and aren't really integrated?

Comment: Thank you, this worked and I have successfully used it to do what I need it to do.